# AssemblyInfo not working when using variables for MSBuild

Tags: batch-file, msbuild, assemblyinfo, msbuildextensionpack

I have the following line that works great

```
<AssemblyInfo AssemblyInfoFiles="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\DesktopAgent\properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" 
              AssemblyCopyright="Copyright 2012 Alpine Access" 
              AssemblyVersion="1.0.0.56"
              AssemblyFileVersion="1.0.0.56">
</AssemblyInfo>
```

I try instead to feed in the line like this but this does not work

```
<AssemblyInfo AssemblyInfoFiles="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\DesktopAgent\properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" 
              AssemblyCopyright="Copyright 2012 Alpine Access" 
              AssemblyVersion="$(VersionNumber)"
              AssemblyFileVersion="$(VersionNumber)">
</AssemblyInfo>
```

The version number in my assemblyinfo file is 1.0.0.32 so in the first case, I actually see it change but the second case is not working :(.

I have a bat file that has this line in it

```
msbuild /property:version=%1;anotherProperty=value project.build
```

and I run the command like

```
build.bat 1.0.0.61
```

and it does not work :(.  Any ideas why it breaks when using properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VersionNumber` must be defined as a property in the project file:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- properties -->
    <VersionNumber Condition="'$(VersionNumber)' == ''">1.0.0.0</VersionNumber>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Then the command must set the same property:

```
msbuild your.csproj /property:VersionNumber=%1
```